# Why are the quantum numbers $n$ and $\ell$ denoted with those letters?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, notation, history, orbitals

We have 4 quantum numbers: principal, azimuthal, magnetic and spin (denoted $n$, $\ell$, $m$ and $s$ respectively). I assume $m$ and $s$ are simply the initials of 'magnetic' and 'spin'. 
Is there any rationale behind the $n$ and $\ell$ denomination?

Comment: Hi Roll - it seemed that you were asking two completely separate questions here. We prefer to have one question per post, so I removed your second question, but I'd encourage you to post it separately.

Comment: Guys, OP is asking for the reason behind the notation, not the physical meaning of the various quantum numbers.

Comment: [Related question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/728/3877) on [hsm.se].

Answer (score 5):

The principle quantum number is denoted $n$ because it is a 'natural number', $n=1,2,3,4....$.

The secondary azimuthal quantum number (also known as orbital angular momentum) is denoted $\ell$ through its association with angular momentum (typically denoted $L$).

Comment: @DanielSank See, this is why I try not to have to many tabs open at the same time. :P Copying-and-pasting has its pitfalls. [Here's](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/728/why-did-angular-momentum-get-the-letter-l) the link, finally.

Comment: Currently, in Floris’s question, the answer is that $L$ itself was inspired by the use of $\ell$ in quantum mechanics; quite the exact opposite from this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You are right to think that $4$ quantum numbers completely describe the state of an electron within an atom. I'll explain each in turn.

$n$ is related to the **energy** of the electron, i.e. the eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian operator. It's called the principal quantum number since we usually think of the energy as the most basic quantum quantity. We use the letter $n$ because we usually take $n$ to be a **natural number**. For example in the case of hydrogen

$$E_n =-13.6eV/n^2$$

$l$ is related to the **total orbital angular momentum**, i.e. the eigenvalue of the angular momentum operator $\mathbf{L}^2$. It's known as azimuthal roughly because angular momentum is associated with rotational symmetry. I'm not aware of a good reason **why we denote angular momentum** by the letter $L$, although a quick Google gives you several options.

$m$ is related to the $z$ **component of orbital angular momentum**, i.e. the eigenvalue of the angular momentum operator $L_z$. It's called the magnetic quantum number because it determines how a (spinless) atomic orbital changes in the presence of a magnetic field.

$s$ is the **spin** of the electron, which can be up or down.

The first three quantum numbers are interrelate, because solving the Schrodinger equation places constraints on which $l$ and $m$ are allowed for each $n$.

For more details, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_quantum_number) Wiki article!

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: @DanielSank - thanks! I reread the question and added some further details which hopefully address the notation issues the OP was talking about.

Comment: Now the answer basically says "I don't know, try Google".

Comment: @DanielSank - I think that's a rather harsh criticism, given the quantity of good physics in the answer, I'm afraid. I was attempting to give my professional opinion that there's no overriding good reason to call angular momentum $L$, but that one could find a number of competing hypotheses on Google. Apologies if I didn't make that clear. I'd be interested to hear your opinion too, though!

Comment: I don't what Daniel is talking about, to me this is a perfect answer considering you even explained the physical ideas behind each quantum number! You had my +1 even yesterday, before the edit. Well done.

Comment: @Phonon: It's good physics but OP asked where the _notation_ comes from and the answer doesn't explain that.

Comment: @DanielSank well to be honest what else is there to say other than it's just a *chosen letter*... Knowing why it's called *n* or *t* is not going to add any important information to it. Although Edward managed to explain the choice of *n* in his edit anyway, as for *l*, it seems like a reasonable choice coming from the analogy of angular momentum *L* in CM.

Comment: " Knowing why it's called n or t is not going to add any important information to it." Dude, that's _precisely_ what the questions asks. Other related topics may be more interesting but that doesn't make them good answers to the question at hand.

Comment: @DanielSank Sigh, I just hate name questions...Presumably if you were to compare it with the choice of *p* for momentum in CM, if I'm not mistaken Newton first spoke of *impulse* in his original work, in Latin *impetus*, since *m* is already used for mass and *i* for component indexing, *p* was the next viable choice. By the same logic, for *angular(angulatis in Latin) momentum*, considering *a*'s already taken for acceleration, *g* for gravity, *r* for radius, *u* sometimes for velocity, I guess it boils down to a choice between *n* or *l*, so *L* seems to have been the preferred choice ;)

Comment: @Phonon The choice of the letter 'p' for momentum may be from the root word of 'impetus' which is the Latin word 'petere', meaning 'to persue'.

Comment: @Phonon: Ok, you're now giving an answer to the original question. However, we _were_ discussing whether or not the answer parent to this comment thread addresses the original question. I maintain that it does not, and you now seem to implicitly agree.