# Orbital Angular Momnetum Explained as simply as possible

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

TL;DR

1. Why is $\ell$ defined as the shape of an orbital?
2. And what relation does angular momentum of the electron have with the shape of the orbital?
3. Why is the $z$-component the magnetism (why does the $z$-component of an angular momentum matrix give magnetism)?

Hello,

So I have just been introduced to basics of qunatum mechanics, and we have been told about the 4 quantum numbers, n, l, m and s, I understand the concepts of n and s, however, my issue lies with l and m.

I don't have any understanding of Hamiltonian operators and angular momentum operators or Schrodinger's equation (I believe these will be taught later). To undertsand l and m I decided to do some research on google, and the definition I find for these 2 numbers is: "l defines the shape fo the orbital and m is the z-component of l". What doesn't make sense is how an integer from 0 to n-1 (l) can define the shape of an orbital which looks to have a complex equation (presumably defined using Schrodinger's equation)? Is l being **assigned** to a certain orbital? As in since we kind of know what the shapes of the orbitlals are supposed to look like we simply index from 0 to n-1 and say that for each l a certain shape is found. Adding on to this, if l is only a number how can it have a z-component which gives m?

To investigate this further, I decided to dig into SE Physics and found [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155005/). However, I barely followed the discussion (due to my lack of understanding on the topic), and found out about the angular momentum operator matrix, where the eigenvalues of this matrix are the values for l and the z compnent of the matrix is m.

However, I have no idea where this angular momentum operator comes from and what it's significance in defining the shape of an oribtal.

So my questions are:

1. Why is $\ell$ defined as the shape of an orbital?
2. And what relation does angular momentum of the electron have with the shape of the orbital?
3. Why is the $z$-component the magnetism (why does the $z$-component of an angular momentum matrix give magnetism)?

Thanks a lot, I know the questions I have will probably be really easy to answer using mathematical formulae, but I am trying to get a feel for this topic, and plus at this point I probably wouldn't understand through formulae, so if someone has good explanation that would be great.

Comment: I think that all the answers to those questions lie in the solution of Schrödinger's eqn for the hydrogen atom. The shape of the orbitals is governed by the spherical harmonics, which is the angular part of the solution of S. eqn. The reason why certain $l$ have sense and why is $l$ a good quantum number is connected to the $SO(4)$ symmetry of the problem. I would argue that a *simple* explanation cannot be given without diving deep into the specific mathematical solution to the problem.

Comment: What is SO(4)? Sorry I am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: $SO(4)$ is the symmetry group of the problem. The hydrogen atom system has $4$-dim rotational symmetry.

Comment: The quantum numbers do not define the shape of the orbitals.  They only *label* them in a useful manner.  The shapes are described by solutions to Schrodinger's equation.  Each shape is associated with a unique value of $\ell$.

Comment: @garyp yes this is what my question was referring to, I was unsure from teh definitions that I read saying the ℓ defines the shape of the orbital, as it didn't make sense, I did some more research and found that ℓ starts at 0 as the s orbital is spherical and has a net momnetum of 0, and hence it goes from 1 to n-1. Thank you, for confirming whether my thinking was correct or not. I haven't learnt Schrodinger's eqn. yet, so I couldn't see that the physical shape is from the solution to it.